# How to extract number together with underscore in python

Tags: python

I have the following data set:

AVE_2020_01_13
AVE_2020_01_15
AVE_2020_01_13
AVE_2020_02_10
AVE_2020_02_10
AVE_2020_02_10
2020_01_29.csv
2019_12_02.csv

I need to extract 2019_12_02.
How to do it ?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
date = string.split("AVE_")[-1].split(".csv")[0]
```

**Explanation**

```
.split("AVE_")[-1] # will take the last entry so if there is no "AVE" in front it will just leave the string as it is. 

".split(".csv")[0]" #  The last part strips away .csv if it exists otherwise leaves the string unchanged
```

**Output**

```
>>> my_list
['AVE_2020_01_13', 'AVE_2020_01_15', 'AVE_2020_01_13', 'AVE_2020_02_10', 
'AVE_2020_02_10', 'AVE_2020_02_10', '2020_01_29.csv', '2019_12_02.csv']
>>> my_new_list = []
>>> for entry in my_list:
...     my_new_list.append(entry.split("AVE_")[-1].split(".csv")[0])
...
>>> my_new_list
['2020_01_13', '2020_01_15', '2020_01_13', '2020_02_10', '2020_02_10', 
'2020_02_10', '2020_01_29', '2019_12_02']
```

Comment: the data set beside "AVE_" , I also have to deal with ".csv".

Comment: thanks a lot. This really help me to move forward for my script!

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
result = re.findall(r'\d+[\d_]+', 'AVE_2020_01_13 AVE_2020_01_15 AVE_2020_01_13
AVE_2020_02_10 AVE_2020_02_10 AVE_2020_02_10 2020_01_29.csv 2019_12_02.csv')
print(result) # ['2020_01_13', '2020_01_15', '2020_01_13', '2020_02_10', '2020_02_10', '2020_02_10', '2020_01_29', '2019_12_02']
```